# Unmarshalling with complex type

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm having trouble unmarshalling XML that represents an invoice in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <Response xmlns="Lamp">
            <Result>
                <Title>The Title</Title>
                <Lines>
                    <anyType xsi:type="InvoiceLine">
                        <Name>Name One</Name>
                        <Quantity>1.0000</Quantity>
                    </anyType>
                    <anyType xsi:type="InvoiceLine">
                        <Name>Name Two</Name>
                        <Quantity>2.0000</Quantity>
                    </anyType>
                </Lines>
            </Result>
        </Response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The Invoice class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Invoice {
    public String Title;
    public List<InvoiceLine> Lines;
}
```

The InvoiceLine class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class InvoiceLine extends anyType {
    public String Name;
    public float quantity;
}
```

And a abstract class for anyType:

```
public abstract class anyType {}
```

This is the code I'm using to do the unmarshalling:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("input.xml");

    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(is);

    xsr.nextTag();
    while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("Result")) {
        xsr.nextTag();
    }

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Invoice.class, InvoiceLine.class);
    javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

    JAXBElement<Invoice> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Invoice.class);
    xsr.close();

    System.out.println(jb.getValue());

}
```

The problem is the Lines list only contains 1 entry with Name=null and quantity=0.0.

-- Edit:

I've just tried adding XmlElement and XmlElementWrapper annotations to both classes, the only change is that the Lines list has no elements.

Modified Invoice:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Invoice {
    @XmlElement(name = "Title")
    public String Title;
    @XmlElement(name = "anyType")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Lines")
    public List<InvoiceLine> Lines;
 }
```

Modified InvoiceLine:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class InvoiceLine extends anyType {
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    public String Name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Quantity")
    public float Quantity;
}
```

-- Edit:
I've just tried making the attributes lower case, but still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly annotating your class fields? I think there's some issue with names starting with uppercase letters and how the JAXB interpreter handles them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my question with your suggestion (I've tried it without the XmlElementWrapper annotation as well). The only change is now the Lines list has 0 elements rather than one empty one.